# Error while building c++ addon, whats the solution for it?

Tags: c++, node.js-addon

[macroizing keywords error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yheBH.png)

Here is the code that I was trying to build:

```
#include <napi.h>

Napi::Object InitAll(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  return export;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(testaddon, InitAll)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not actually used, `export` is a keyword in C++, so `return export` is a syntax error (as is pretty much any other attempt to use `export`).

At a guess, `InitAll` is probably intended to return the same `Napi::Object` it received as a parameter, so that should be `return exports;` instead.